# direct copy vs virtual copy constructor (clone function)

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

It has been two days I'm trying to understand why do we need clone function( virtual copy constructor).

I created a simple example (code below): :

```
 #include <iostream>
 
  class Dog
  {
  public:
      Dog() { std::cout << "I am a Dog\n"; }
      virtual Dog* clone() { return new Dog(*this); }
      virtual void info() { std::cout << "info : I am a Dog\n";}
  };
  
  class RedDog : public Dog
  {
  public:
      RedDog() {std::cout << "I am a RedDog\n"; }
      RedDog* clone() { return new RedDog(*this); }
      void info() { std::cout << "info : I am a RedDog\n"; }
  
  };
  
  void foo(Dog* pd)
  {
      Dog* temp = pd;
      //Dog* temp = pd->clone();
      temp->info();
  }
  
  int main()
  {
      Dog d;
      std::cout << "########################\n";
      RedDog rd;
      std::cout << "########################\n";
      foo(&rd);
      return 0;
  }
```

There is no difference between using clone in foo function and using normal copy.
it will execute the function of appropriate object.

Please show me in an example simple that if I don't use clone there will be problem, or usage of clone.

Thanks

Comment: please if you can explain me in this example, there might be some similar questions but they are not clear for me, so if you could  explain me what is the limit of not using clone() it would be great

Comment: What makes you think that `Dog* temp = pd;` is calling *any* member function of *any* object? All it does is copy a pointer's value from one place to another.

Comment: Did you try `Dog d = *pd;` ? *That* would be a "normal" copy.

Comment: `Dog* temp = pd; temp->info();` is equivalent to `pd->info();`. You're just copying a pointer, not creating a new dog.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a real use-case for `clone()` or anything like that in C++, especially since C++11 introduced move semantics. It just doesn't make sense with C++ semantics and philosphy. Copy is expressed with pass-by-value, and it's explicitly stated to the caller that this value will be copied.

Comment: There is no such thing as **virtual copy constructor** in C++.

Comment: @AnoopRana The "cloning" approach is often called "virtual copy constructor", since that's the intended effect.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok, i wasn't aware of that(that cloning approach is often informally called as virtual copy ctor). Though, the term *virtual copy constructor* is not a formally defined term.

Comment: Moreover, `virtual clone()` function will always have the flaw of deciding where the object is allocated, and it usually has to allocate on the heap. With copy constructor, user gets to choose where to allocate their objects, gets to select the lifetime, doesn't have to remember to `delete` it afterwards etc.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen _"I don't think I've ever seen a real use-case for clone()"_. Suppose you have a graphic editor. A scene may be represented as a container of (unique) base class-pointers to graphic objects. Then, a user selects some objects and wants to duplicate them. How would you done this without virtual cloning?

Comment: Just some general hints to your code (not answering your question): Use the override specifier for your info() and clone() functions in the class RedDog.

Comment: @WhozCraig , so as you said Dog d = *pd is a normal copy and the problem of this normal copy is that it works for objects whose type is specific at compile time and if there is an object which its type will be specified at runtime by the user then this normal copy doesn't copy the appropriate object ( it does copy just the Dog or Dog proportion) and clone is the way to decide at runtime what object to be copied.

Comment: so as @Yksisarvinen said we have a graphic editor, and we want to give the user ability to copy some object from the graphic editor, for example there is object circle and object square and we don't know what actual object he will copy till the runtime. if there is no mechanism to copy the appropriate object at run time all the copies will be from base object.  < Out of topic :  you know c++ is getting more like theory instead of programming for me:-) I don't know maybe because I am new and it takes time to understand practical stuff >

Comment: @DanielLangr You're right, copying a `unique_ptr` (or any base pointer) would be a potenatilly good use-case for `virtual clone()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The clone function is used with factories. These provide an object based on given input. An implementation is to have a map enums linked to each needed object known as the base class. So if your input specifies a red dog, you call the function `Dog* getDog(enumDog newDog)` and it gives you your needed object if it was provided to the map before.

An alternative for this is switch-case with all the enums.